# Umask difference between 0022 and 022

Tags: unix, file-permissions, umask

Is there any difference between umask `0022` and `022`?  I want to change my umask to `022`.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no difference between umask `0022` and umask `022`.

The octal umasks are calculated via the bitwise AND of the unary complement of the argument using bitwise NOT.

**Set the umask like this:**

```
el@apollo:~$ umask 0077
el@apollo:~$ umask
0077
el@apollo:~$ umask 0022
el@apollo:~$ umask
0022
```

**Brief summary of umask value meanings:**

umask 077 - Assigns permissions so that only you have read/write access for files, and read/write/search for directories you own. All others have no access permissions to your files or directories.

umask 022 - Assigns permissions so that only you have read/write access for files, and read/write/search for directories you own. All others have read access only to your files, and read/search access to your directories.

umask 002 - Assigns permissions so that only you and members of your group have read/write access to files, and read/write/search access to directories you own. All others have read access only to your files, and read/search to your directories.

**For more information about what umask does:**

How to set your default umask, see this article: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

If you want more detailed information this is an interesting article: http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/7/17/umask-and-unusual-file-permissions-and-types

The answers to this post also offer some insight into umask bits:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056912/question-about-umask-in-linux

Comment: "The octal umasks are calculated via the bitwise AND of the unary complement of the argument using bitwise NOT. " I guess an example would be: arg = 4; "unary complement of the argument using bitwise NOT" = ~arg = 011 (binary); "bitwise AND" = 111 & 011 = 011 = 3