# Why is git clone changing file permissions

Tags: git

Why does the file permissions for all my WordPress files are being changed when I clone?

The directories are 775 when they are supposed to be 755 and files are 664 when they are supposed to be 644.

What's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your config on the server where you are cloning:

```
git config core.sharedRepository
```

- If it is set to `group`, it would set the writable bit automatically.
- If it is set to `umask`, it would depends on your local umask.

More generally, check your `umask` (as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5264968/6309)).

The [OP Kenny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3109595/kenny) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667859/why-is-git-clone-via-ssh-is-changing-file-permissions/23670805#comment36398674_23670805) that setting [`umask` to `0022`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056950/6309) works.
The articles referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13269502/6309) detail what it involves in term of security.

> The default `umask 002` used for normal user. With this mask default directory permissions are 775 and default file permissions are 664.
>
> A `umask` of `022` allows only you to write data, but anyone can read data.

Comment: I run that command but nothing happens. it doesn't show what it's set to. am I missing something?

Comment: @Kenny no, that just means your config isn't set for `core.sharedRepository`. What does `umask` return?

Comment: umask is returning 0002. should I change it?

Comment: @Kenny yes `0002` means `775`. try `umask 0022`.

Comment: yes!! it's working! thanks a ton! are there any possible security issues with changing it to 0022?

Comment: @Kenny Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibilty, and added some references regarding security.

Comment: thanks a ton for your help @VonC. the internet is so amazing :)