# jgit - cloning a repo creates files with my default umask permission and not the permissions in the repo

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am using jgit to clone my repository, but when I do, I notice that the permissions are not what they're supposed to be.  They match my umask setting which is undesirable since git can track the permissions and that is critical for the configuration files.

Is this possible or is it simply a bug?

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in "[Why is git clone changing file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23670805/6309)", you would need to use:

```
git config core.sharedRepository group
```

(or otherwise, Git would respect the umask)

However, you need to check if JGit does support that config (that [wasn't the case in the beginning](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/wiNxuwuxKwo))

Note that [Git only store 644 and 755](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25225524/6309).

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, my question was clear for jgit.  I don't have this issue at all with git.

Comment: Then that config is still not supported by jgit, which precisely answer your question