# Git permissions to a file

Tags: git, file, permissions, execution

I am uploading my files to git repo with the permissions rwx on local system, But it is not showing the executable permission when I clone them from git repo to some other local system. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: The question sounds incomplete. Did you really do `git add <PATH>` when the file was marked as x? Make sure that the file is attributed with `100755` when `git ls-tree @ <PATH>` first. If it's not for whatever reason, try setting the flag in the index with `git update-index --chmod=+x <PATH>`, and then commit (amend, rebase, whatever). Of course the target file system should support the x-flag.

Comment: @Sak What is the umask on your other local system? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23670805/6309)